# TypeError: inverse_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: machine-learning

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder as le

names = ['Virat', 'MS', 'Shikhar', 'Rohit']

names_encode = le().fit(names)

Y = names_encode.transform(names)

le.inverse_transform()
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

> in ()
>   ----> 1 le.inverse_transform(Y)
>
> TypeError: inverse_transform() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `inverse_transform` the proper object and you need to specify the object that you want transformed (`Y` in your example, or `l` in my added example). Try this:

```
# code from question
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder as le
names = ['Virat', 'MS', 'Shikhar', 'Rohit']
names_encode = le().fit(names)
Y = names_encode.transform(names)

# code that works
names_encode.inverse_transform(Y)

# or if you have a specific list of encoded names like l
l = [0, 1, 1]
# you could run
names_encode.inverse_transform(l)
```